# Problem with generated SQL from Hibernate (MS SQLServer)

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, orm, jpa

I have a problem with Hibernate generating an SQL that do not work on SQLServer (works on PostgreSQL without any problems). I have tried to set the hibernate dialect for SQLServer but the same SQL is still generated and still do not work. The HQL query looks like this:

```
 select count(t) from ValidationLog t
```

The generated SQL looks like this:

```
 select count((vl.dataKey, vl.dataType)) from ValidationLog vl;
```

So my question is if there is anyway around it? Would really like to have the same code for both databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the JPA specification, your JPQL query is perfectly **valid**:

> #### 4.8 SELECT Clause
>
> ...
>
> The SELECT clause has the following
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> select_clause ::= SELECT [DISTINCT] select_expression {, select_expression}*
> select_expression ::=
>      single_valued_path_expression |
>      aggregate_expression |
>      identification_variable |
>      OBJECT(identification_variable) |
>      constructor_expression
> constructor_expression ::=
>      NEW constructor_name ( constructor_item {, constructor_item}*)
> constructor_item ::= single_valued_path_expression | aggregate_expression
> aggregate_expression ::=
>      { AVG | MAX | MIN | SUM } ([DISTINCT] state_field_path_expression) |
>      COUNT ([DISTINCT] identification_variable | state_field_path_expression |
>           single_valued_association_path_expression)
> ```

However, you might be a victim of a bug reported in issues like [HHH-4044](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4044), [HHH-3096](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3096), [HHH-2266](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2266) (or even [HHH-5419](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5419)).

Possible workaround: use a *state_field_path_expression*.

```
select count(t.someField) from ValidationLog t
```

Comment: But it is not SQL that SQL Server would ever recognize as t-sql doesn't have that capability.

Comment: @HLGEM What SQL? The currently generated? If yes, then I agree it is incorrect, which is exactly the problem (according to the spec, the JPQL query from the OP is correct, it's up to the JPA provider to generate the appropriate SQL).

Answer (score 0):

The HQL looks wrong to me, should be:

```
select count(t.dataKey) from ValidationLog t
```

Comment: No, it is a composite key in the table so there has to be at least two columns.

Comment: What are you trying to count? The number of rows or distinct composite keys?

Comment: Number of rows in the tables is what I would like to count. Which should be the same as the number of distinct composite keys.

Comment: In that case my answer still stands.